# Aurelia.js Single Page Application Keycloak Authentication Example

Tags: angularjs, single-page-application, aurelia, keycloak

I need an example or pointers for using Keycloak.js authentication in an Aurelia.js-based single page web application.  In my use case, a user should be able to access my web SPA before login.  However, to gain access to additional resources, user will need to log in.  No problem with with the backend apps.  'Just need web-client help.

I have basic HTML5 and Angular.js examples.  It seems the example provided by [bandrzejczak](http://bandrzejczak.com/blog/2015/11/22/single-sign-on-with-keycloak-in-a-sigle-page-application-part-1-slash-2-angular-dot-js/) comes the closest.

'Have already searched throughout the web, read the Keycloak, Aurelia, Aurelia-Auth, Aurelia-Authorization docs.  I have spent way too much time on this and am hoping someone has already solved this problem.  -- Thanks

Comment: see [this](https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/techniques-for-authentication-in-angularjs-applications-7bbf0346acec#.mp9rjwttn)

Comment: I'm not sure about keycloak, so I won't post an answer, but I wrote up a few blogs on best practices for aurelia authentication, as well as a template. [aurelia auth 1](http://davismj.me/blog/aurelia-login-best-practices-pt-1/), [aurelia auth 2](http://davismj.me/blog/aurelia-auth-pt2/) and [aurelia template](http://davismj.me/portfolio/sentry/)

Comment: Thanks Matthew, I had already pulled up your blog.  You provided some nice insights into how to integrate an authorization service within Aurelia.  I believe I'm about there on the Keycloak part.  I'll post any solution(s) I come up with.  I've been more of a java enterprise/server side developer.  And on that side, Keycloak is awesome for integration and has an excellent set of capabilities.

Comment: Thanks @pro.mean.  Although your solutions are targeted for Angular, I appreciate the patterns and concerns you cover.  Good write-up and some education for me.

Answer (score 1):

See [Aurelia-Keycloak](https://github.com/waynepennington/aurelia-keycloak).

## Aurelia-Keycloak

**Alpha version.**  An authentication plugin based on **KeyCloak**  for **Aurelia**  applications.

### Get Started

- Install Aurelia-Keycloak:

  jspm install aurelia-keycloak
- Add keycloak configuration and initialization settings:

Follow Keycloak directions for creating a keycloak.json configuration file.  Put this file in the same directory as your application's index.html file. Refer to the keycloak javascript adapter [documentation](https://keycloak.gitbooks.io) for its initialization options and API.

- Add plugin to your app's main.js. This example assumes your keycloak.json is in your root directory.  This code will immediately cause the login screen to appear.
  `.plugin('aurelia-keycloak', {initOptions:{ onLoad: 'login-required' }})`
- To defer login, use the following:
  `.plugin('aurelia-keycloak')`
  Then, construct a login button within your code to call the keycloak login function.
- Rather than use a keycloak.json file, you can insert the installation config with the plugin declaration

`.plugin('aurelia-keycloak',{install:{**PASTE GENERATED KEYCLOAK.JSON HERE**}},initOptions:{ onLoad: 'login-required' }}

**See the GITHUB for details.**